# Issues finding average of a list and its sublists

Tags: python, numbers

I can't seem to figure out why my averages in the code below are wrong when I use a mix of positive and negative numbers.
any help is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

```
my_num = []


while True:
    n = input("Enter a number (-9999 to end):")

    if n == '-9999':
        break               # if user enters -9999 it will come out of loop

    my_num.append(int(n))   # adding the numbers with append function

avg = sum(my_num)/len(my_num)   #using sum and len function to determine averages

avgpos = sum([ x for x in my_num if x>=0 ])/len(my_num)

avgneg = sum([ x for x in my_num if x<0 ])/len(my_num)


print("the list of all numbers entered are:")
print(my_num)

print("The dictionary with averages is:")

my_dict = {'AvgPositive': avgpos, 'AvgNonPos': avgneg, 'AvgAllNum': avg}

print(my_dict)
```

Answer (score 3):

Your averages are wrong because your denominators are wrong for calculating the partial averages

```
avgpos = sum([ x for x in my_num if x>=0 ])/len(my_num)

avgneg = sum([ x for x in my_num if x<0 ])/len(my_num)
```

In the above, you are taking the correct sum, but the incorrect length.

Instead, use the appropriate lengths

```
pos = [ x for x in my_num if x>=0 ]
neg = [ x for x in my_num if x<0 ]

avgpos = sum(pos)/len(pos) if len(pos) else None
avgneg = sum(neg)/len(neg) if len(neg) else None
```

Note that I am using the [ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/394809/1860929) above, because otherwise the above code may raise `ZeroDivisionError` if either of the lists `pos` or `neg` is empty (i.e., the cases when all numbers entered are positive, and when all numbers entered are negative).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the issue:

```
avgpos = sum([ x for x in my_num if x>=0 ])/len(my_num)

avgneg = sum([ x for x in my_num if x<0 ])/len(my_num)
```

You're summing the set of positive/negative numbers but using the set of all numbers to do so!

Try:

```
avgpos = sum([ x for x in my_num if x>=0 ])/len([ x for x in my_num if x>=0 ])

avgneg = sum([ x for x in my_num if x<0 ])/len([ x for x in my_num if x<0 ])
```

Comment: True. I was answering only the question that was asked.

Answer (score 0):

Let me introduce you to the filter and lambda:

```
pos = filter(lambda x: x>=0 and x,my_num)
neg = filter(lambda x: x<0 and x,my_num)
avgpos = sum(pos)/len(pos)
avgneg = sum(neg)/len(neg)
```

Answer (score 0):

i think the easiest way is with numpy:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array(my_num)
avg = a.mean()
avg_pos = a[a > 0].mean()
avg_neg = a[a < 0].mean()
```